# How to edit HTML page (in a webview) from Javafx without reloading the page?

Tags: java, html, javafx, webview, javafx-webengine

This is how I load my page and I would like to modify it while it's in the browser

```
    WebView browser = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = browser.getEngine();
    String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String name = "\\src\\web\\index.html";
    engine.loadContent(getPATHtoHTML(cwd + name));
```

Comment: You can refresh the page using the same method with new content: `engine.loadContent("new Content...")`; To edit HTML you have to use `javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DOM document is available and can be modified. This updates the content of the  `WebView`. The following example simply appends some text to the body, but more complex manipulations are possible:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
    engine.loadContent("<html>"
            + "<body></body>"
            + "</html>");
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    Button button = new Button("add");
    button.setOnAction(evt -> {
        String text = textField.getText();
        Document doc = engine.getDocument();
        Element element = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
        element.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(text));
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(webView, textField, button));

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

If you also want to modify the file, you could also output the result to a file:

```
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(engine.getDocument());
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outputFile);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
transformer.transform(domSource, result);
```

Comment: I had to trick your code a bit to work with mine but it works perfectly thanks!